# How to divide a Grand total of a pivot table by a fixed number?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a several slicers attached to a pivot table. I need to divide the grand total of this Pivot table (regardless of what slicers are chosen) to a number - which doesn't change to find a percentage.

Id imagine this to be pretty simple but am having a complete mind blank :(

I have tried Sumifs, and Ifs statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the grand total to ignore any slicer settings, you could

- create a separate pivot table that only calculates the grand totals and is not connected to the slicers
- use formulas to create the grand totals based on the pivot source data, not the pivot table.